# Bug caused by use of function instead of sub in single line lambda expression

Tags: .net, vb.net, lambda

I've just come across a situation where a colleague wrote a bug and we didn't understand why it happened despite the fact we know how to fix it.  I've been using lamda expressions for years but am much more experienced with C# than VB and I obviously have a fundamental misunderstanding of something.

The following is observed in Visual Studio 2010 with .Net 3.5.

I've simplified this down to the following simple test code that reproduced a similar scenario:

On a windows form I put the following, to simply execute a lambda and then print the value of a test object to a textbox:

```
Private Sub ExecuteAction(ByVal action As Action(Of TestClass))
    Dim testObj As New TestClass()
    action(testObj)
    TextBox1.Text = testObj.MyInteger
End Sub

Public Class TestClass
    Public MyInteger As Integer
End Class
```

and then I run some code to call it using a lambda.

In the following case the output in the textbox is 15 as I would expect :

```
ExecuteAction(Sub(obj) obj.MyInteger = 15)
```

In the following case the output is also 15 as I would expect (it does generate a warning because no return value is specified which I understand and is fine because it does what is expected) :

```
ExecuteAction(Function(obj)
                 obj.MyInteger = 15
              End Function)
```

In the following case the output is 0 and I do not understand why:

```
ExecuteAction(Function(obj) obj.MyInteger = 15)
```

Why in the final scenario does the value of the object not change to 15?  I need to understand this difference between single line function lambdas and multi line function lambdas to see if I need to check across all our products for similar bugs.  It compiles fine and does not generate warnings making it extremely dangerous for our uses.

I tried the following to see if it made any difference forcing the execution before any implicit Return but it did not:

```
ExecuteAction(Function(obj) (obj.MyInteger = 15))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between the multi line and the single line functions is that one contains a statement and the other contains an expression.

When `obj.MyInteger = 15` is a statement then `=` is the assignment operator. When it is an expression then `=` is the comparison operator.

The multi line version of your single line function is:

```
ExecuteAction(Function(obj)
  Return obj.MyInteger = 15
End Function)
```

This will compare the values and return a boolean value. As an `Action(Of TestClass)` is expected, there is no requirement on the type of the return value, so you don't notice that it returns a boolean value.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense.  Obviously the direct situation couldn't happen in C# because it has == for comparision and = for assignment which confused me.  I'll make sure our programming standards are updated and make a judgement call on checking for how likely this is to have caught us out elsewhere.  Thanks again.